# Can we achieve the following using an Excel formula? The output of the formula will be the Result column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

| Month | Brand | Product | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| January | Apple | Iphone | Apple:Iphone,Ipad,Imac;Lenovo:Yoga,Thinkpad |
| January | Apple | Ipad | Apple:Iphone,Ipad,Imac;Lenovo:Yoga,Thinkpad |
| January | Apple | Imac | Apple:Iphone,Ipad,Imac;Lenovo:Yoga,Thinkpad |
| January | Lenovo | Yoga | Apple:Iphone,Ipad,Imac;Lenovo:Yoga,Thinkpad |
| January | Lenovo | Thinkpad | Apple:Iphone,Ipad,Imac;Lenovo:Yoga,Thinkpad |
| February | Apple | Imac | Apple:Imac;Lenovo:Thinkpad |
| February | Lenovo | Thinkpad | Apple:Imac;Lenovo:Thinkpad |

Comment: That depends on the version you are using.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you very much. I am using MS Office 365

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In D2 put:

```
=BYROW($A$2:$A$8,
    LAMBDA(a,
        LET(rng,a,
            mb,$A$2:$B$8,
            m,$A$2:$A$8,
            b,$B$2:$B$8,
            p,$C$2:$C$8,
            TEXTJOIN(";",,UNIQUE(
                 BYROW(FILTER(mb,m=rng),
                 LAMBDA(a,INDEX(a,,2)&":"&
                    TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTER(p,(m=INDEX(a,,1))*(b=INDEX(a,,2)))))))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm! Just one more request. There are users using other versions of Excel that does not have lambda function. Is there any other alternate for them?

Comment: No.  It will need to be vba then.

Comment: Another option, not worth adding as a new answer: `=SUBSTITUTE(REDUCE(BYROW(A1:A7,LAMBDA(a,TEXTJOIN(",",0,,FILTER(B1:C7,A1:A7=a)))),UNIQUE(B1:B7),LAMBDA(a,b,SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(a,","&b&",",";"&b&":",1),","&b&",",","))),";","",1)`